# Inline_requests error: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python, scrapy

I was trying to install scrapy-inline-requests using "pip scrapy-inline-requests" but got the error below. I have checked the documentation and can't seem to figure out what is wrong. Any suggestions please?

```
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/inline_requests.py'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to python it-self. It's your operating system (linux I suppose) that deny the access to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/...`. Add `sudo` at the begin of the command line (assuming you know the root password of your machine):

```
sudo pip scrapy-inline-requests
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do `sudo pip install` followed by the package name. It's not a scrapy problem.